# Microsoft Speech Recognition Service Factory audio format

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

It says in the documentation that *"The audio must be PCM, mono, 16-bit sample, with sample rate of 8000 Hz or 16000 Hz."*

Say I want to use the DataClient, I get the audio as bytes. How can I convert it to that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to convert your byte array to an InputStream. Then, you create an AudioInputStream from that Inputstream using your AudioSystem. Once you have your audio stream, you essentially have audio and you can write it to file or do whatever you like.

ByteArrayInputStream oInstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ayAudioData);
AudioInputStream oAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(oInstream);